# Pasar el valor de una variable javascript a php

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente código, en donde lo que intento hacer es que detecte que explorador es el que se está usando, pasando una variable de JS a php, pero lo que consigo es el texto:

```
 <script>           
      var browser = '';
      var browserVersion = 0;

      if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          browser = 'Opera';

      } else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          browser = 'MSIE';

      } else if (/Navigator[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
          browser = 'Netscape';

      } else if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          browser = 'Chrome';

      } else if (/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          browser = 'Safari';

          /Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
          browserVersion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
                      
       } else if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          browser = 'Firefox';
                    
       }
       
       if(browserVersion === 0){
          browserVersion = parseFloat(new Number(RegExp.$1));
       }
          
          alert(browser + "*" + browserVersion);
                        
             
 </script>

 <?php
     // igualar el valor de la variable JavaScript a PHP             
     $var_PHP = "<script> document.writeln(browser); </script>"; 
      
     // muestra el resultado 
     echo $var_PHP ;  
      
      if( $var_PHP == "Safari"){
         echo "ok"; 
      
      }else{
       echo "No";
       }
  ?>
```

Pero la variable **$var_PHP** me trae lo siguiente:

```
<script> document.writeln(browser); </script>
```

Me gustaría que me diera el valor del `Browser` ¿que me recomendarían hacer?

Comment: No puedes evaluar variables de javascript en php.  Investiga sobre la relacion entre cliente y servidor.  Tambien investiga sobre ajax.

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas una petición ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mover datos de JavaScript a PHP con Ajax.
Un ejemplo con JQuery sería:

```
let bar = 'bar';
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'parser.php',
        data: { 
            'foo': bar
        },
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Con un parser.php tal que así:

```
<?php
echo ($_POST ['foo']);
```

E incluyendo el js desde index.php:

```
<?php
echo ('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>');
echo ('<script src="index.js"></script>');
```

PD: para conseguir info del browser desde php tienes $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] y get_browser().
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Según el comentario primero es necesario pensar en la relación entre cliente y servidor, su Javascript se ejecutará en el cliente, no en el servidor. Esto significa que `Browser` no se evalúa en el lado del servidor y, por lo tanto, su valor no se puede escribir en un archivo en el servidor.

La mejor forma de pensar en este proceso es como si estuviera generando un archivo de texto de forma dinámica. El texto que está generando solo se convierte en código ejecutable una vez que el navegador lo interpreta. Solo lo que coloca entre `<?php` etiquetas se evalúa en el servidor.

Por cierto, hacer un hábito de incrustar piezas aleatorias de lógica PHP en HTML o Javascript puede conducir a un código seriamente complicado. Hablo por experiencia propia.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sencilla es en el html crear un input de tipo oculto con un ID, en javaScript le das el valor y en el php obtienes el valor por el ID.

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.